# Recursively copy one directory to another, if files don't match

Tags: java, file-io, apache-commons

I have a service that will be populating a directory that I need to copy to another directory periodically. The source will be populated periodically.

When I copy the directory, it will be quite large, so I only want to add files in the destination, or overwrite files that aren't the same file (e.g. file size mismatch or modification date).

Is there a simple way to do this? I'm aware of [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyDirectoryToDirectory-java.io.File-java.io.File-), but it's unclear to me if it will always ovewrite all the files, and what "merge" means here, specifically if it will not copy files that already match.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Instead of checking file sizes, you should check the new file's hash against the old file's hash

Comment: This is similar to what 'rsync' command does. Have you scoured the net for Java implementation of what rsync does? Probably better than re-inventing the wheel. Some of them might support compression for faster copy.

Comment: @PillHead Looking at the FileUtils source code, copyFIle() does just blindly overwrite the file.

Comment: @Veera I was unfamiliar with rsync. I do see some rsync implementations that might do the trick, but it would be nice to have a soultion that doesn't rqeuire installing cygwin.
https://github.com/fracpete/rsync4j

Comment: @StealthRabbi - That looks more like a wrapper to the actual rsync command and not a Java implementation of rsync. However, if rsync command is accessible to your program, use the rsync command directly.

Comment: you're right, FileUtils will overwrite by default.  you could use FileUtils.copyDirectory with your own implementation of FileFilter which checks whether the destination file exists and has the same length and last modified time as the src file

Answer (score 1):

[Files.walkFileTree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitor-) and the other methods of Files can do it:

```
public void copyTree(Path source,
                     Path destination)
throws IOException {

    Files.walkFileTree(source,
        new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir,
                                                     BasicFileAttributes attr)
            throws IOException {
                Path destPath = destination.resolve(source.relativize(dir));
                Files.createDirectories(destPath);
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file,
                                             BasicFileAttributes attr)
            throws IOException {

                Path destPath = destination.resolve(source.relativize(file));

                FileTime sourceTime = Files.getLastModifiedTime(file);
                FileTime destinationTime = Files.getLastModifiedTime(destPath);
                if (!Files.exists(destPath) ||
                    sourceTime.compareTo(destinationTime) > 0) {

                    Files.copy(file, destPath,
                        StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES,
                        StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                }

                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
}
```